# Merging two lists in Haskell - alphabet and Int

Tags: haskell, merge

I was given merge as below:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs    
merge [] ys = ys    
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y    = x : merge xs ys    
    | x <= y    = x : merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

and

```
type Var = String
```

now I want to merge ['a' .. 'z'] with [1....] to create infinite list of variables. ['a1','b1','c1'...'z1','a2','b2',...'z2',...]

I have defined my variables as below:

```
variables :: [Var]
variables = merge ['a'..'z'][1..]
```

But I'm getting below error:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [Var]
        Actual type: [Char]
    • In the expression: merge ['a' .. 'z'] [1 .. ]
      In an equation for ‘variables’:
          variables = merge ['a' .. 'z'] [1 .. ]
   |
50 | variables = merge ['a'..'z'][1..]
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

what am I getting wrong here ? Please help...thanks in advance!

Comment: The two items should be of the same type.

Comment: You could convert both input lists into lists of String first. Those can then be merged.  Or write a different function that is specialised to take two lists of the types you have here (Char and Int)

Comment: The `merge` here aleso does not look like it will create a list with `a1`, `b1`, etc. It simply will make an ordered list that is the union of two other ordered lists.

Comment: `merge [a,b] [1,2]` will return `[1,2,a,b]` not `[a1, b1, a2, b2]`

Comment: For your task, the `merge` function seems to be useless. I'd forget about using that, and search for some other alternative e.g. using a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks very much all, I will convert both into the same data type and try to use list comprehension.